# Terminal Image editor utility for MAC OS

Tags: software-rec, macos, images

I am dealing with the analysis of many PostScript graphs on my macOS system. Could you suggest me some utility that could be executed in terminal with the aim to add some information to the graph in one line command syntax?

```
utility -i image_1.ps -t "add some text on image" -o image_1_processed.ps
```

For instance I need to add the name of the particular file to the desired location of this graph. Before I used convert from ImageMagic package (doing same on Linux), but now I am searching for alternative solutions.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, ImageMagick is also available for macOS via Homebrew. Would that be an option?

Comment: yes! but there is a problem with its installation for my mac, I've already asked developers ... that's why I was looking for other sollutions working in similar manner

Comment: Would it not be better to resolve the ImageMagick issue then? What's the issue with installing ImageMagick via Homebrew? If it doesn't work, then you probably don't have a standard macOS system.

Comment: it has been solved !!